# Do I need to rebuild indexes after importing a .bacpac into a database?

Tags: sql-server

Do I need to rebuild indexes after importing a .bacpac into a database
or does the database takes care automatically?

Comment: You will get your db in the exact same state as it was on a source. If the indexes were already rebuilt and your usage of this db is readonly, definitely you should not. If your workload freagments your indexes you should rebuild them periodically. This absolutely does not depend on the fact of imorting. It depends only on your data structures and your db activity

Comment: [See Paul Randall's post on this](https://serverfault.com/a/33454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such magic in SQL Server!

Although, IMO it would be a great if Microsoft provide such options in the future.

So, you have to do rebuilding indexes on your own.

The good starting point is a set of scripts provided by Ola [SQL Server Backup, Integrity Check, and Index and Statistics Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/).